# How to add new lines inside P tag from server side by passing message p.InnerText

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tags, innertext

I am using a p tag with id p1.

```
<p id="p1" runat="server" ></p>
```

I have a message which I am passing from server side which is stored in variable "message".

```
This is first line
This is second line
```

I am passing this value to the p tag by

```
p1.InnerText=message.
```

My question is, How to add new line in the p tag from server side as shown above?
I have tried 
 but it is not working :

```
"This is firstline"+"<br/>"+"This is second line"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` between strings.

For example

```
"This is firstline" + Environment.NewLine + "This is second line"
```

**Update 1:**

You can use it like :-

```
Function1("This is firstline" + Environment.NewLine + "This is second line");

Public void Function1(string value)
{ 

  p1.InnerText=value

}
```

If it not work than please try :-

```
p1.InnerHtml = newLine
```

**Update 2:**

With `<pre>` you need to use `"\n"` instead of `Environment.NewLine`

```
<pre id="test" runat="server"></pre>

test.InnerText = newLine;
```

Comment: I will explain a little more detail: 

Function1("This is firstline" + Environment.NewLine + "This is second line")

Public void Function1(string value){
p1.InnerText=value}


This is how it is and I have tried this as well. But it is not working

Comment: Thanks for the update. But in the function we should it as single value as I have shown in the example
Function1("This is firstline" + Environment.NewLine + "This is second line")

Comment: It is working with innerhtml.  I was asking, Is there any way to make it work with InnerText?

Comment: No you can't use it, instead of it you can use <pre> tag. I am editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
p1.InnerHtml = "This is firstline"+"<br/>"+"This is second line";
```

It will work

Comment: I will explain a little more detail: 

Function1("This is firstline" +"<br/>" + "This is second line")

Public void Function1(string value){
p1.InnerText=value}

This is how it is and I have tried this as well. But it is not working

Comment: I had cross checked ..It is working fine  
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value="This is firstline"+"<br/>"+"This is second line";
        call(value);}                      
 protected void call(string value)
    {
        p1.InnerHtml = value;
    }

Comment: It is working with Innerhtml
I was asking, Is there a way to make it work in InnerText?

Comment: InnerHTML lets you enter HTML code directly, InnerText formats everything you put in there for it to be taken as plain text. For example, if you were to enter this in both properties:   you use "This is firstline"+"<br/>"+"This is second line" using innerhtml u will see a beakline beteen but if you use innertext  the resulting htm wil be This is firstline &lt;br b&gt; This is second line..Hope you understand the difference betwwen two different things.

Comment: Okay... Thanks Bhasin

Answer (score 0):

If you want new lines in the original string to be shown in the paragraph, you must use the `InnerHtml` property and add `<br />` tags instead of newline chars/strings. But that means you need to take care of html encoding the strings yourself. Something like this would work:

```
void Function1(string value)
{
    var messageRows = value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string oneRow in messageRows)
    {
        builder.Append(Server.HtmlEncode(oneRow) + "<br />");
    }
    p1.InnerHtml = builder.ToString();
}
```

Test it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text_with_newlines = "part 1" + Environment.NewLine + "part 2" + Environment.NewLine + "part <script type=\"javascript\">alert('boo!');</script>";
    Function1(text_with_newlines);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as raw string:

```
string string = String.Format(@"This is firstline. {0}This is second line.", Environment.NewLine);
```

It works.